# Extract only the link from string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract link from this below mentioned string.

```
 str = /url?q=http://www.example.com/services/blog/first-article&sa=U&ei...
```

I used the following regular expression to get that link.But it fetches the full url  after "http" because I mentioned the pattern to be.What I want is to get only URL before the pattern "&sa" (ie) `"http://www.example.com/services/blog/first-article"`

```
 links = re.findall(r'/url\?q=(http://.*)', str)
 print links  # http:example.com/services/blog/first-article&sa=U&ei...
```

Comment: Why not `r'/url\?q=(http://.*?)&sa=.*'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regular expression you need:

```
links = re.findall(r'/url\?q=(http://[^&]*)', str)
```

In words: get everything after `/url?q=`, starting with `http://` and which doesn't contain a `&` character.